# laravel blade include passing data to parent

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i have  blade file view  like this

```
<?php $a=1; ?>
 @include('view_bind_array_form',['a'=>$a]); 
<?php dd($a); ?>
```

and contain in view_bind_array_form

```
<?php

  $a=5;

 ?>
```

i want to replace $a to 5(like value of include)

but in this case $a still have value 1;

questions 
1. how to replace value $a after calculating in include blade and return result calculating

can u help. please

Comment: try this `@include('view_bind_array_form',['a' => &$a])`;

Comment: still in value 1 :(

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do this by using [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) variables generally in php.

```
<?php global $a; $a=1 ?>
 @include('view_bind_array_form'); 
<?php dd($a); ?>
```

And in your child blade

```
<?php global $a; $a=5;?>
```

Note that you do not need to pass it in the `include` function as it accesses the global variable directly.